# How to properly interact with the docker client within a container

Tags: docker, flask

I am writing a small application with flask which is meant to interact with the docker api in order to run containers on demand. I would like to deploy this application within a docker container. However, I understood that it is relatively bad to mount the docker socket, as it has root privilege on the local host.

Is there a proper method to access the docker api within a container in order to avoid this caveat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is mounting the Docker socket to an unprivileged container a bad idea?**
In order to mount the unix socket to your Docker container, you would need to change the permissions of the Docker daemon socket. This, obviously, could give non-root users the ability to access the Docker daemon, which might be a problem if you are worried about privilege escalation attacks.  ([source](https://integratedcode.us/2016/04/08/user-namespaces-sharing-the-docker-unix-socket/))

**Do I really need to secure the Docker socket?**
This depends on your usecase. If you have many users on your server, and are particularly worried about a non-privileged user affecting your app, then definitely secure the socket.  If this is a virtual machine that is completely dedicated to the app, insecure might be easier.

**How do I interact with the socket insecurely?**
Just change the permissions ([described here](https://integratedcode.us/2016/04/08/user-namespaces-sharing-the-docker-unix-socket/)) and then mount the socket to the container.  It's that simple.

**How do I interact with the socket securely?**
I think there are two good ways of doing this:

1. Restart the Docker Daemon with TLS Authentication enabled.  Rather than accessing the unix socket, access it using `HTTPS` with a signed SSL key.  More instructions on setting that up can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/#create-a-ca-server-and-client-keys-with-openssl).
2. Use an Authorization Plugin on the unix socket as described [here](https://integratedcode.us/2016/04/20/sharing-the-docker-unix-socket-with-unprivileged-containers-redux/).